# Tab inside single sherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

Isn't possible to have tabs to single SherlockFragment?

In my app., i used ActionBarSherlock with sliding menu.,and for each slidingMenu contents i have created 4 fragments., in that for a single sherlockFragment class i need to use tabs.

how it is possible.,Any ideas !!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the SherlockFragment sample, you will find an example of how to use tabs inside a fragment
http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/fragments

Comment: hm this is i am using.,but this is not i exactly i want!. i am already using sliding menu so all my classes are sherlockFragments., so for one of the sherlockfragment i need video view and below with tabs. can u get it?